# Is there a function or combination of POSTGIS functions that can be used to generate centerline from a polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc01c.png)I want to create a centerline from a polygon and I have tried using both ST_StraightSkeleton and st_approximatemedialaxis functions in PostGIS. It gives an error with a message "straight skeleton of Polygon with touching interior rings is not implemented" and in other instances "CGAL failed to create straightSkeleton".I have tried alternative answers on this platform generating similar errors.

Here is the code I used in the database

```
select
    ogc_fid, 
    subtype, 
    subtypecod,
    st_approximatemedialaxis(geom) as geom
from 
    sometable
```

Is there a proper way to go about this issue?

[image: Polgyon]
[image: Centerline that I want to generate]

```
Here is the sample data: <https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/896986/Polygon_5.zip>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add a data sample and the exact result you expect? Cheers

Comment: I guess that your polygons are actually multipolygon. Can you run this function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html  and let me know if your data is ST_MultiPolygon

Comment: I have included the images. @milad, the data is multi polygon. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is related to the fact that your data is multipolygon.
Try ST_Dump() to change your data from multipolygon to polygon:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html

Then,run your query again.

your query for dumping should be like this:

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom AS geom
INTO sometable2
FROM sometable;
```

Then, run https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html

Comment: Thanks, @milad. I have tried your suggestion but the query still came back with the error message "CGAL failed to create straightSkeleton"

Comment: I guess that your polygon is complicated (intersection of boundary edges).
This function cannot deal with this input. You can select your polygons by id and run the function. This way you will find out which polygon(s) are problematic. Then if you share the photo of the problematic polygons maybe I have a suggestion.